# Is it possible to restore deferred constraints after setting SET CONSTRAINTS ALL IMMEDIATE?

Tags: postgresql

I am using pgtap to test some deferred constraint triggers by:

- Opening a transaction
- Inserting some test data
- Performing some statements
- Simulating a commit by using `SET CONSTRAINTS ALL IMMEDIATE`
- Testing post-commit conditions

This works fine, but it limits me to a single test per transaction. If I try and set up more data later, my previously deferred constraints now fire immediately.

Is it possible to revert the affect of `SET CONSTRAINTS ALL IMMEDIATE`, without reverting the effects of the constraints that it caused to activate? If not, my only option is to move each test to a separate file, which is a little bit cumbersome.

Comment: Do you mean `SET CONSTRAINTS ALL IMMEDIATE`?

Comment: Yes, I do, thanks - I've edited my question. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried

```
SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED
```

*after* you call `SET CONSTRAINTS ALL IMMEDIATE`?

If that would defer more constraints than you want to, you'll have to name them individually:

```
SET CONSTRAINTS my_constraint [, ...] DEFERRED;
```

It does not revert any effect. It only defers further checks. If a constraint is violated, an `EXCEPTION` is raised. There is nothing that *could* be reverted here.

You could catch the exception in a plpgsql function if that is what you want.

If you ant to revert constraints to their initial state, you'll have to `SET` them individually and with the explicit state. Sadly - to my knowledge - there is no "RESET CONSTRAINTS" in PostgreSQL 9.1 that would bring them all to their initial state.

[Manual page.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-set-constraints.html)

Comment: Constraint violations are fine, that would fail the test which is OK. The problem with just doing a sweeping 'ALL DEFERRED' feels like I risk putting myself in a state that doesn't represent the start of a transaction, which isn't quite ideal.

Comment: In this case, you'll have to `SET` involved constraints individually. Sadly - to my knowledge - there is no `RESET CONSTRAINTS` that would bring them all to their initial state.

Comment: I thought as much. I'm accepted your answer based on that comment, maybe you want to add that into the actual body of the answer?